# @RequestMapping in spring not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new in Spring MVC. I created one controller `newController.java` in `springproject`. My code is below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Receiver", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void recvHttpGet(Model model) {
    System.out.println("here get");
    newmethod();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/Receiver", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void recvHttpPost(Model model) {
    System.out.println("here post");
    newmethod();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String show(Model model) {
    return "index";
}
```

web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>ClassPath:/spring/applicationContext.xml, ClassPath:/spring/hibernateContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>

</servlet-mapping>
```

whenever I try to run it then `index.jsp` page is shown but whenever I try to call `/Receiver` url it shows a 404 error. Please help me. Also when I changed in `recvHttpGet` method  `return "index"` it also shows a 404 error. Also nothing is wrote to the console.

I wants to just check which method calls so wants to write in console window but it does not show anything.

Comment: Why don't you return any views in the `recvHttpGet` and `recvHttpPost` methods?

Comment: I am just checking that that methods called or not?what to do for calling this methods?

Comment: You should add your spring MVC config, also a `web.xml` extract.

Comment: @RC Please check now.my web.xml file.

Comment: Is you application deployed without any errors? I suspect `ClassPath:/spring/applicationContext.xml, ClassPath:/spring/hibernateContext.xml` not loaded properly. Just enable `debug` and check the logs.

Comment: could you give us your servlet-context file ?

Comment: @Niranjan Thanks for your reply but i setted ClassPath for both applicationContext.xml and hibernateContext.xml.Its successfully loaded i think.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a JSP page, just like `return "index";`

If you have a receiver.jsp page in views, then...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Receiver", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String recvHttpGet(Model model) {

    return "receiver";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply but i tried same thing but same error shows up.

Comment: Does the file `receiver.jsp` exist in `WEB-INF/views` ?